# How to make a table that looks like this in html or make a tableless one

Tags: html, css

I have a to present data in html with headers. Below is the image of part of the header which i am struggling with.

[image]

I have managed to rotate the text but the problem is there overlap.

This is the code of the whole structure.

```
<style type="text/css"> .text-rotation {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
            -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)";
            height:inherit;
            }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="5" align="center" valign="bottom">Code</td>
    <td rowspan="5" align="center" valign="bottom">Change</td>
    <td rowspan="5" align="center" valign="bottom">Description</td>
    <td colspan="6" align="center" bgcolor="#FF6666">STOCK RANGE</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#66CC00" >SPHERICAL</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC00" >SPH/CYL-/-</td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#0066CC">SPH/CYL+/-</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#66CC00" class="text-rotation">MINUS</td>
    <td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#66CC00" class="text-rotation">PLUS</td>
    <td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC00" class="text-rotation">MINUS</td>
    <td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC00" class="text-rotation">PLUS</td>
    <td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#0066CC"  class="text-rotation">PLUS</td>
    <td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#0066CC" class="text-rotation">MINUS</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick mock-up:

```
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">STOCK RANGE</td>
        <td colspan="11">LENS PROPERTIES</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan ="2">SPHERICAL</td>
        <td colspan ="2">SPH/CYL</td>
        <td colspan ="2">SPH/CYL</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Stock</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Disclaimer</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Index</td>
        <td rowspan="2">UV Coating</td>
        <td rowspan="2">FOOBAR</td>
        <td rowspan="2">FOOBAR</td>
        <td rowspan="2">FOOBAR</td>
        <td rowspan="2">FOOBAR</td>
        <td rowspan="2">FOOBAR</td>
        <td rowspan="2">FOOBAR</td>
        <td rowspan="2">FOOBAR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LEFT1</td>
        <td>LEFT2</td>
        <td>LEFT3</td>
        <td>LEFT4</td>
        <td>LEFT4</td>
        <td>LEFT5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DATA_LEFT_1</td>
        <td>DATA_LEFT_2</td>
        <td>DATA_LEFT_3</td>
        <td>DATA_LEFT_4</td>
        <td>DATA_LEFT_5</td>
        <td>DATA_LEFT_6</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_1</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_2</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_3</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_4</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_5</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_6</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_7</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_8</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_9</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_10</td>
        <td>DATA_RIGHT_11</td>
    </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

EDIT 2: Some visual of this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ze6bz/)

EDIT 3: Some new visuals with the other answer incorporated: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ze6bz/3/).

Comment: I have gone through the solution you provided. Its what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rotating an item in non legacy-IE calculates it's properties *before* rotating the element. This means the whole item and background will be shifted outside the document flow, probably not what you want in a table. Try rotating the cell content, not the cell itself, like so:

```
.text-rotation > * {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)";
        height:inherit;
}
```

... and adding a generic `display:block` wrapper around the cell content ...

```
<td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#66CC00" class="text-rotation"><div>MINUS</div></td>
<td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#66CC00" class="text-rotation"><div>PLUS</div></td>
<td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC00" class="text-rotation"><div>MINUS</div></td>
<td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC00" class="text-rotation"><div>PLUS</div></td>
<td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#0066CC" class="text-rotation"><div>PLUS</div></td>
<td rowspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#0066CC" class="text-rotation"><div>MINUS</div></td>
```